# Access parent class variable from method, used by another class

Tags: javascript

I have two classes which are not related:

```
class A {
    myVar = null;

    myFunc() {
        console.log(this.myVar)
    }
}

class B {
    constructor(func){
        this.func = func;
    }

    callFunc() {
        this.func();
    }
}
```

My problem is the following:

```
let a = new A();
let b = new B(a.myFunc);
b.callFunc();
```

This will be `undefined` because `this` in `console.log(this.myVar)` won't refer to the instance of class `A`, but the instance of class `B`. How can I access the global variable of class `A` when calling the function from another class?

Comment: Either use `this.func.call(a)` in `callFunc`, or pass `() => a.myFunc()` as the argument to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`a.myFunc.bind(a)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), specifying that you want `myFunc`'s `this` to refer to the `a` instance.

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value

Also, don't forget your `new` operators :)

```js
class A {
    myVar = "Hello world";
    myFunc() { console.log(this.myVar) }
}

class B {
    constructor(func){ this.func = func; }
    callFunc() { this.func(); }
}

let a = new A();
let b = new B(a.myFunc.bind(a));
b.callFunc();
```

Comment: Fantastic! This worked. Thanks for the reminder as well, I will edit the question - it's just a simplified example.